# does aws rds serverless scaling help current running query?

Tags: amazon-aurora, aws-serverless, aws-aurora-serverless

I have an aws aurora severless rds. Once in awhile, i have queries run which involve a large number of records being joined and/or updated.

When a resource intensive query kicks off, and the serverless environment scales up.. does the query that is currently running actually get to make use of the new resources, or is it only for future queries?

I am testing this out right now (if i can).. I ran the large query and it wasn't returning after 30 minutes.. (i have seen this query return in 5 minutes in the past).  I'm not sure how to tell what 'scaling' has occurred.. but assuming it has scaled up while this query has been running.. I killed the query, and then just ran the process again. Unfortunately this is a many-part process.. so I'm now waiting to see if it runs any faster.

So I guess its a 2 part question:
is there a simple way to see the current scaling 'level'?  eg. see that it has raised, and then later, see it lower itself back down..

when the scaling increases, and a query is currently running.. will that query actually get to take advantage of the scaling, or only future queries?

Thanks

Comment: as a follow up, i do believe my query ran faster after i killed it, and just rerun it. SO i tend to believe that the scaling does NOT help current running queries, just furture ones.. But I'd love to hear a definitive answer from someone who knows?  and I'd love to know if I can easily see when tha scaling goes up/down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not help currently running queries, because in order to scale, Aurora has to find a scaling point. This is defined as a period with no active transactions/queries. If a scaling point cannot be found before the timeout is reached, scaling would either be abandoned or forced, depending on the configured TimeoutAction (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ScalingConfiguration.html). Forced scaling would kill any open connections. Your running query would therefore block scaling until it completes.

You can see the current capacity of your cluster in the Amazon RDS console. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.viewing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can probably have better luck in this scenario if you are running a recent enough version to use Aurora Serverless v2:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.html

The business with scaling points, where scaling only helps future queries, applies only to Serverless v1.

There are settings you can look at from the AWS Console to show the current capacity settings for a cluster, either Serverless v1 or v2. But for simplicity what I normally do is just show the current size of the buffer pool (MySQL) or shared buffers (PostgreSQL). That can be done from any client session. Serverless v1 scales always by doubling or halving the memory size; Serverless v2 scales up and down in increments as small as 0.5 ACUs (corresponding to 1 GB of RAM).